# Setting of Environmental variable in StartWeblogic.sh linux

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables, weblogic-10.x

I have to set environmental variable in the JAVA_OPTIONS of startWeblogic.sh

in Windows i set as

set JAVA_OPTIONS=-DCommonFilePath="" -Dwindow.title=App-Name -Dsimulator.context_path=/SiteMinder

the above statement works fine in Windows

But if i try to set in Linux, its not taking it.

JAVA_OPTIONS=-DCommonFilePath="" -Dwindow.title=App-Name -Dsimulator.context_path=/SiteMinder

on server startup its showing "-DCommonFilePath=""" file or directory doesnot exist.

Please Help me on this.

Comment: Where did you try to set that Environmental Variable?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put quotes around the value of `JAVA_OPTIONS` and escape the quotes in `-DCommonFilePath=""`, like so:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-DCommonFilePath=\"\" -Dwindow.title=App-Name -Dsimulator.context_path=/SiteMinder"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write proper shell command:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS='-DCommonFilePath="" -Dwindow.title=App-Name -Dsimulator.context_path=/SiteMinde'
```

it means enclose in `'` (better would be `"` but it is used in your command already), make sure whether part -DCommonFilePath="" is correct, I suspect it should be -DCommonFilePath="." for **this** directory, or even better put there absolute path (you'll be sure that it is correct)

and you need to export environmental variable before use:

```
export $JAVA_OPTIONS
```

do not forget on `$`. And you can try to use it. If you don't want to make it each time you run your app put those command into your **bash_profile**